# How do I obtain a copy of the ANSI C standard?

Tags: c, standards, ansi-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

I keep hearing about this 'ANSI C' standard, like it was some legal document my compiler somewhat conforms to, but I've never actually seen the document myself.

Anywhere know where I can pick up a copy, or is it only intended for the eyes of compiler-developers?

Comment: Information here: http://www.lysator.liu.se/faq/c-faq/c-5.html

Comment: See [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Answer (score 1):

http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO%2FIEC+9899%3A1999

As far as I know, there's no (legal) way to obtain a free copy of it.

Comment: Time to set up my paypal, then.

Comment: There's other places to get it by the way.  That was just the place I first thought of to search for it.  Might be able to find it somewhere cheaper (Ray Toal's link has some cheaper options).

Comment: I find it amusing that a compiler developer needs to pay for the spec but will need to release it for free so it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get to the actual standard that you can download freely is a draft from the working group: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Considering that you just want to look over it and not write a compiler, it should suffice for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've read large portions of the latest drafts, mostly while answering questions here.  I have not read the official standard.

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) specifically about getting copies of the standard, official and draft (non-official).

Comment: Who needs those standards then? :) Compiler makers?